# Pycrypto - Using Crypto.Random to generate a secret key and an initialisation vector

Tags: python, pycrypto

Can Crypto.Random be used to safely generate a strong secret key and an initialisation vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [PyCryto docs](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#crypto-publickey-public-key-algorithms), the answer is yes:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
rng = Random.new().read
RSAkey = RSA.generate(1024, rng)
```

Comment: `ValueError: RSA modulus length must be a multiple of 256 and >= 1024` in my `(2, 6, 0, 'final', 0)`

Comment: A secret key and initialization vector is used for block ciphers and block cipher modes of operation such as AES-CBC, not RSA.

Answer (score -2):

Using pycrypto([This link for more info](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-and-cryptography-with-pycrypto/))

```
>>> from Crypto.Hash import MD5
>>> MD5.new('abc').hexdigest()
'900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72'
```

More security([For more info](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/vdi.html))?

```
>>> from versile.quick import VCrypto, VX509Crypto
>>> purpose  = 'Versily Python Demo Services'
>>> personal = 'I like Monty Python humor'
>>> password = 'kLqnr37ubG'
>>> identity = VCrypto.lazy().dia(1024, purpose, personal, password)
>>> type(identity)
<class 'versile.crypto.local._VLocalRSAKey'>
>>> x509_pubkey = VX509Crypto.export_public_key(identity.public)
>>> print(x509_pubkey) 
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBANpspNSQPXlq/tEBIq8pT31WYzcKFtX8b41k9ec5YqiJhgOf9WyK0UqTScOzLiySKun2
XBVjXRhok5kvyT32K+JYh2VwoOnS0J6KFOhaatKMvDmVIFyhAdZ7xC3+jf1zT0n/vAQE0+DEGKfS
de7je8eA/T4C7uwLKn98aY+oudFtAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: What does versatile.crypto have to do with PyCrypto? And using a MD5 hash is not a secure method that uses PyCrypto.Random either.